# Unable to set localhost. This prevents creation of a GUID

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-swarm

I'm struggling with the following issue. We have a Java application that is running properly on Docker. Now, when we try to migrate the application to Docker Swarm--running it as a service--it always throws the following exception:

```
 Cache - Unable to set localhost. This prevents creation of a GUID. Cause was: 39bc5cdfb3d9: 39bc5cdfb3d9: Name or service not known
java.net.UnknownHostException: 39bc5cdfb3d9: 39bc5cdfb3d9: Name or service not known
```

Note that `39bc5cdfb3d9` is the container ID.

I've tried the following:

1. `curl` against the DNS that we are using
2. updating the `nginx` config that the other server is back up

Setup:

1. 3 Mangers
2. containers runs only on the 2 servers app1.dev and app2.dev it has a constraint label=dev
3. using the default network ingress,

DNS:dev-ecc.toroserver.com
I run the service using this:

```
     docker service create \
            ${HTTP} \
            ${HTTPS} \
            ${VOLUMES} \
            ${ENV_VARS} \
            ${LICENSE} \
            ${LOGS} \
            --limit-memory 768mb \
            --mode=global \
            --constraint 'engine.labels.serverType == dev' \
            --env appName="${SUB_DNS}" \
            --name="${SUB_DNS}" \
            --restart-condition on-failure --restart-max-attempts 5 \
            --with-registry-auth \
            ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/${DOCKER_USER}/${APPNAME}:${VERSION}
```

Also I've got this error every time I tried to login, it will automatically logout my session , Not sure if it is related to the error Unable to set localhost

```
2017-11-08 03:25:56,771 [ INFO] AjaxTimeoutRedirectFilter - User session expired or not logged in yet
2017-11-08 03:25:56,771 [ INFO] AjaxTimeoutRedirectFilter - User session expired or not logged in yet
2017-11-08 03:25:56,778 [ INFO] AjaxTimeoutRedirectFilter - Redirect to login page
2017-11-08 03:25:56,778 [ INFO] AjaxTimeoutRedirectFilter - Redirect to login page
2017-11-08 03:30:36,822 [ INFO] AjaxTimeoutRedirectFilter - User session expired or not logged in yet
2017-11-08 03:30:36,822 [ INFO] AjaxTimeoutRedirectFilter - User session expired or not logged in yet
```

Any insights will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How you are starting/configure swarm with the java application, can you please share them.

Comment: Edited my post. I included there how I start the service.

Answer (score 1):

The "**Cache - unable to set localhost**" looks to be a common error message from the [EHCache project](http://www.ehcache.org/). Finding that in the code shows that it is the result of calling the Java net library's `java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost()` method, which looks up the local hostname and then tries to DNS resolve it to an IP address.

A quick local test shows that this works for both `docker run` and as a service on my single-node Swarm. Given you mention testing DNS, maybe at this point more information is required about your specific Swarm setup (specifically networking) to see why you are getting different behavior. Obviously if you have your own DNS, then as per the above, the default name of the container **must** be resolvable by a DNS lookup or else you will continue to get the Java `UnknownHostException`.

Comment: I updated my post and included the setup and how I run the service. Thanks for responding anyway.